# Facebook Page with Event and Maximum Capacity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I need to setup an event on a Facebook Page.  I would like to be able to set a capacity for this event, and once capacity has been met, I would like to close the event.  Is there any way to do this?

I know I can do this with a custom solution integrating the GRAPH API but I need this all to live on the Facebook Page.  I can't find anything in Facebook to set an event capacity or even fire an event when someone RSVPs so I could manually close the event.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [events](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) are not yet supported as a [real time subscription](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime) so your best bet is to:

1. create a cron-job
2. grant the `offline_access,create_event,user_events` permissions
3. Check the `attending` connection periodically
4. When it meets a certain number, edit the `privacy` property to `CLOSED`

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't seen the real time subscription services yet.  Those look handy for other things at least